# Pass Parameter to Querystring AND Fire Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I have a search function that returns an arraylist of objects to my form. I am iterating through the list using JSTL's foreach tags.

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="contact" varStatus="loop">
<div style="padding: 5px;">
${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}
<br>
${contact.primaryPhone}
<br>

//Is this the proper way to set up the url?
<a href="Contacts?search=${param.search}&id=${loop.index}">View Contact</a>

</div>
<br>
</c:forEach>
```

When the user clicks the link inside each row, the row index is passed to the querystring and at this point I would like to show a div that contains additional information about the user.

I have a javascript function that I use to display the div and center it on the screen bla bla bla, but my question is how do I refresh the page with the index loaded into the querystring and then fire my javascript function?

I considered using:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.id}">
//Check if id in querystring is available and if so, display popup
</c:if>
```

To check if there was an index available in the querystring, but I don't think there is a way to fire my function from within a JSTL tag.

Should I be doing something on the server side when I request back to the servlet rather than trying to handle this on the client side? I just figure its a waste to requery my database and set another request parameter, when I already have the information I need stored in a parameter than I am using to display my list anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually came up with is to check for my id parameter in the querystring each time the page loads (with javascript)

```
function init(){
console.log("Contacts page loaded.");

//Loads popup if 'id' is present in the querystring.
if(getQuerystring('id', 'null') !== 'null') {
    showCenteredDiv('popup');
}
};
```

The function I use to check the querystring is:

```
//Search querystring for a specific parameter. Second arg is the value to display if its not found.
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";

  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);

  if(qs == null) {
    return default_;
  } else {
    return qs[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a script tag within the parameter check, and run whatever you want within it. For example, set some variable that you can test later on, when the page finished loading.
Or, if you embed the parameter check late enough in the page, just invoke your function.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.id}"> 
    <script>
        runSomeFunction();
    </script>
</c:if>
```

Comment: This does work, but in order to maintain a cleaner html and keep all javascript in an external file, I came up with another solution.